# Flutter Equatable package not working with Datetime format in UTC (Z)

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing

So I have a class called ClockPair with I extended with Equatable

```
  const ClockPair({
    required this.userId,
    required this.duration,
    required this.clockIn,
    required this.clockOut,
    required this.typeIn,
    required this.typeOut,
  });

  final String? userId;
  final num? duration;
  final DateTime? clockIn;
  final DateTime? clockOut;
  final int? typeIn;
  final int? typeOut;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        userId,
        duration,
        clockIn,
        clockOut,
      ];
}
```

When the DateTime variables (eg clockIn) ends with Z equatable will not work

`2024-01-01 22:00:00.000Z == 2024-01-01 22:00:00.000Z  // false`

`2024-01-01 22:00:00.000 == 2024-01-01 22:00:00.000  // true`

In the unit tests I will get something like this

Expected: [
ClockPair:ClockPair(6ad70ab3-96d1-460f-a11f-e423660abadb, 7200000, 2024-01-01 22:00:00.000Z, 2024-01-02 00:00:00.000Z),
ClockPair:ClockPair(6ad70ab3-96d1-460f-a11f-e423660abadb, 3600000, 2024-01-02 00:00:00.000Z, 2024-01-02 01:00:00.000Z)
]

Actual: [
ClockPair:ClockPair(6ad70ab3-96d1-460f-a11f-e423660abadb, 7200000, 2024-01-01 22:00:00.000Z, 2024-01-02 00:00:00.000Z),
ClockPair:ClockPair(6ad70ab3-96d1-460f-a11f-e423660abadb, 3600000, 2024-01-02 00:00:00.000Z, 2024-01-02 01:00:00.000Z)
]

Which: at location [0] is ClockPair:<ClockPair(6ad70ab3-96d1-460f-a11f-e423660abadb, 7200000, 2024-01-01 22:00:00.000Z, 2024-01-02 00:00:00.000Z)> instead of ClockPair:<ClockPair(6ad70ab3-96d1-460f-a11f-e423660abadb, 7200000, 2024-01-01 22:00:00.000Z, 2024-01-02 00:00:00.000Z)>

Why is it not it is now working with UTC time?
Am I missing something in the ClockPair class?

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with comparing UTC `DateTime` objects.  Can you please provide a minimal but complete example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I am preparing a sample code. Just a note, the unit test is passing if I check each value by itself

`expect(result[0].clockOut, clockPairsTest[0].clockOut);`
`expect(result[1].clockOut, clockPairsTest[1].clockOut);`